# How to create a list of lists of integers from DataFrame?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame:

```
Values    Values2
1,2,3,4   0,2,3
2,1,0,6   0,0,0
9,8,7,6   1,0,1
```

I want to create list of lists. I do that in following way:

```
df[['Values']].values.tolist()
```

In output a get:

```
[['1,2,3,4'],
 ['2,1,0,6'],
 ['9,8,7,6']]
```

It's a strings but I need a lists of integer like that:

```
 [[1,2,3,4],
  [2,1,0,6],
  [9,8,7,6]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems they are stored as a string. Try the following (not very robust, but depending on your context it can be ok):

```
slist = df[['Values']].values.tolist()
ilist = [ [int(s) for s in l[0].split(',')] for l in slist]
```

Comment: I would compare performance of this solution and the one in the other answer before deciding what to implement. This seems simpler, but is not using `pandas` native methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) to split the string on comma, with `expand=True` this will separate each value into it's own column, you can then convert the type to `int` and then get the values in a list as desired:

```
In [109]:
df['Values'].str.split(',',expand=True).astype(int).values.tolist()

Out[109]:
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 0, 6], [9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

Breaking this down:

```
In [110]:
df['Values'].str.split(',',expand=True)

Out[110]:
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  1  0  6
2  9  8  7  6

In [111]:    
df['Values'].str.split(',',expand=True).astype(int).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
0    3 non-null int32
1    3 non-null int32
2    3 non-null int32
3    3 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(4)
memory usage: 128.0 bytes
```

To handle `NaN/None` values use `to_numeric` with `stack` and `unstack`:

```
In [114]:
pd.to_numeric(df['Values'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack(), errors='coerce').unstack().values.tolist()

Out[114]:
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 0, 6], [9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

Comment: TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: That means you have invalid or an empty string which was not in your original sample data in your question, please update your question with the relevant sample